# How to I adjust the height of a PlotWidget?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am developing a spectrum analyzer GUI, and I am plotting an FFT using `matplotlib.pyplot`, and a waterfall display beneath it using `PyQtGraph`. The waterfall display is created using an `ImageItem`, which is added to a `PlotWidget`, which is then added beneath the FFT in a `QVBoxLayout`. This is the result:

[image: Spectrum Analyzer Plot (FFT/Waterfall)]

I had to use `PyQtGraph` for the Waterfall display because MatPlotLib was unable to plot the data quickly enough. Now, I cannot figure out how to adjust the size of the `PlotWidget` so that the two graphs are approximately the same size. The `ImageItem` is being generated using

```
ImageItem.setImage(dataArray)
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you should use scale in first update

```
counter += 1
    if counter == 1:
        ImageItem = pg.ImageItem()
        ImageItem.scale((data_storage.x[-1] - data_storage.x[0]) / len(data_storage.x), 1)
```